# jquery hover() not firing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I have a ASP.NET user control with the below markup:

```
<div>
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<table id="t1"><tr>...<td class="myclass"><span>First Name:</span></td>...<\tr> <\table>
</script>

<table id="t2"><tr>...<td class="myclass"><span>First Name:</span></td>...<\tr> <\table>
<\div>
```

I want to fire the hover() for all classes with class="myClass". I have placed the below code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".myClass").hover(
  function() {
      alert('in...');
  },
  function() {
      alert('out...');
  });
}
```

The problem is .hover() fires for td element in table "t2" but not for "t1". Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.hover adds the event handler statically.

Try doing

```
$(".myClass").live("hover",
  function() {
      alert('in...');alert('out...');
  }
}
```

Comment: I couldnt get the part of firing twice... can you please post the exact code now?

Comment: <table>
<tr>
<td><input id="txtFirstName" value="${FirstName}" type="text" /></td>

<td class="myClass">
<input id="txtDOB" value="${DOB}" type="text" />
</td>  
</table>

When I hover the mouse on the textbox, the alert fires and when i move the mouse again (not over the td element but anywhere), the alert fires again.

$(".myClass").live("hover",
  function() {
      alert('in...');
  }
);

Basically I want to display a div on the hover of the textbox, so if you have any code, it will really help.

Comment: Instead of <table> <tr> <td><input id="txtFirstName" value="${FirstName}" type="text" /></td> <td class="myClass"> <input id="txtDOB" value="${DOB}" type="text" /> </td> </table> try this <table> <tr> <td><input id="txtFirstName" value="${FirstName}" type="text" /></td> <td> <input class="myclass" id="txtDOB" value="${DOB}" type="text" /> </td> </table>

Comment: just to make  a note: all i have done is put the textinput as a part of the class rather than the <td>

Comment: The code doesn't help. Just wondering what is making the alert to fire twice?

Comment: I am getting alert twice - once when you hover over the textbox, the 2nd one when you click OK on the alert and move the mouse.

Comment: Note that .live() is now deprecated. You should use .on()

Comment: '..statically.' what does that mean

Answer (score 1):

"t1" is within a jQuery template. I guess this template has not been inserted into the DOM when your ready-function gets executed. Therefore it's not there and no event is attached. You have two possibilities: either you fire your function after the template has been inserted or you use the ["delegate"-function of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) which binds an event to all existing and future elements.

Comment: I can see the html for the template getting loaded on the page load. So, document.ready should be able to find this markup, unless it ignores the mark up within the <script> tags, makes sense?

Comment: You can ensure it's really there on the page load by inserting an `alert($('#t1'));` right at the beginning of your ready-function.

Comment: The template is not part of the DOM until it is bound or appended to a DIV. everything works after then!

Answer (score 0):

maybe because the HTML for t1 is in script tags? Or is that how jQuery templates work?

Comment: The template is not part of the DOM until it is bound or appended to a DIV. everything works after then!